# How to arrange the table using php, javascript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

This is a php and javascript.  I have a row consist of classcode, courseNumber,courseDescription,units,time,days,room the problem is I could not arrange it. It displays all data in the column of courseDescription. Below is the picture what it looks like now and how I want it to be.

[https://plus.google.com/u/0/112172241812600096315/posts/Du8f6rHsEtY?pid=6147544934724622242&oid=112172241812600096315][1]
javascript

```
      $(document).ready(function() {

$("#faq_search_input").watermark("Begin Typing to Search");

$("#faq_search_input").keyup(function()
{
var faq_search_input = $(this).val();
var dataString = 'keyword='+ faq_search_input;
if(faq_search_input.length>3)

{
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "search.php",
data: dataString,
beforeSend:  function() {

$('input#faq_search_input').addClass('loading');

},
success: function(server_response)
{

$('#searchresultdata').html(server_response).show();
$('span#faq_category_title').html(faq_search_input);

if ($('input#faq_search_input').hasClass("loading")) {
 $("input#faq_search_input").removeClass("loading");
        } 

}
});
}return false;
});
});
```

home.php

```
 <div id="SubjectOffering" class = "listTable" >
                 <p><h3> Subject Offering </h3> </p>
                 <p>
                     <div class = "searchBar">
                        <form id="searchbox" action="#" onsubmit="return false;">
                              <!-- The Searchbox Starts Here  -->
                <input  name="query" type="text" id="faq_search_input" />
                <!-- The Searchbox Ends  Here  -->




                        </form>

                    </div>
                </p>
                <p>
                <table>
                     <tr>
                        <td>Class Code</td>
                        <td>Course Number</td>      
                        <td>Course Description</td>

                        <td>Time</td>
                        <td>Days</td>
                        <td>Room</td>
                      </tr>

                     <tr>
                        <td></div></td>
                        <td></td>       
                        <td><div id="searchresultdata" class="faq-articles"> </td>
                        <td> </td>
                        <td> </td>      
                        <td></td>
                        <td> </td>
                      </tr>
                      </table>
```

search.php

```
 <?php
 include_once ('connections.php');

 if(isset($_GET['keyword'])){
  $keyword =    trim($_GET['keyword']) ;
  $keyword = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $keyword);

     $query = "select courseCode,classcode,courseDescription,time,day,room      from class where classcode like '%$keyword%' or courseDescription like '%$keyword%' or courseCode like '%$keyword%' or time like '%$keyword%'
  or day like '%$keyword%' or room like '%$keyword%'";

 //echo $query;
 $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
 if($result){
 if(mysqli_affected_rows($dbc)!=0){
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){

 echo '<p> <b>'.$row['classcode'].'</b> '.$row['courseCode']. '</b>'.$row['courseDescription'].'</b> '.$row['time'].'</b> '.$row['day'].'</b> '.$row['room'].'</p>';
     }
    }else {
    echo 'No Results for :"'.$_GET['keyword'].'"';
   }

 }
 }else {
echo 'Parameter Missing';
 }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has few html tag errors like unused tags are there. I just revised your code. Please verify if you found any errors still just let me know.

Your **JAVASCRIPT / JQUERY** code should be as the following:

```
/**
 * @description: Update result when user searches.
 * @author Vivek Keviv
 * @params none
 * @return none
 */
$ (document).ready(function() {
    $("#faq_search_input").watermark("Begin Typing to Search");
    $("#faq_search_input").keyup(function() {
        var faq_search_input = $(this).val();
        var dataString = 'keyword='+ faq_search_input;
        if (faq_search_input.length>3) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "search.php",
                data: dataString,
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('input#faq_search_input').addClass('loading');
                },
                success: function(server_response) {
                    $('#searchresultdata').html(server_response).show();
                    $('span#faq_category_title').html(faq_search_input);
                    if ($('input#faq_search_input').hasClass("loading")) {
                        $("input#faq_search_input").removeClass("loading");
                    } 
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Your **HTML** code should be as the following:

```
<div id="SubjectOffering" class="listTable">
    <p>
        <h3>Subject Offering</h3>
    </p>
    <div class="searchBar">
        <form id="searchbox" action="#" onsubmit="return false;">
            <!-- The Searchbox Starts Here  -->
            <input  name="query" type="text" id="faq_search_input" />
            <!-- The Searchbox Ends  Here  -->
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="searchresultdata" class="faq-articles">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Class Code</th>
                <th>Course Number</th>      
                <th>Course Description</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Days</th>
                <th>Room</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>       
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>      
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your **PHP** code should be as the following:

```
<?php
include_once ('connections.php');
if (isset($_GET['keyword'])) {
    $keyword =    trim($_GET['keyword']) ;
    $keyword = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc, $keyword);

    $query = "select courseCode,classcode,courseDescription,time,day,room      from class where classcode like '%$keyword%' or courseDescription like '%$keyword%' or courseCode like '%$keyword%' or time like '%$keyword%'
    or day like '%$keyword%' or room like '%$keyword%'";

    //echo $query;
    $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
    if ($result) {
        if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc)!=0) { ?>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Class Code</th>
                    <th>Course Number</th>      
                    <th>Course Description</th>
                    <th>Time</th>
                    <th>Days</th>
                    <th>Room</th>
                </tr>            
                <?php while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $row['classcode']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['courseCode']; ?></td>       
                            <td><?php echo $row['courseDescription']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['time']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['day']; ?></td>
                            <td><?php echo $row['room']; ?></td>
                        </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </table>
        <?php } else {
            echo 'No Results for :"'.$_GET['keyword'].'"';
        }
    }
} else {
    echo 'Parameter Missing';
}
?>
```

Thanks & Regards,

**Vivek**

Comment: @Maecece Liz Always try to use indentation in the code so that you can understand it easily and also able to debug and identify blocks of code or else surely you will be confused. 
**NOTE:** Don't leave spaces between class attribute and its values like the following: `class = "searchBar"` use like `class="searchBar"`

Comment: I changed the code please check. I'm sorry i didnt run code and gave you. I just checked with naked eye and made corrections and gave.